how can I tell the function to look into and take the value of a specific index of a list, whose values get updated?
I've created a class, whose object falcon_visual_vectors holds each vector I add to it and the class is also responsible for updating the vectors coordinates i.e. in main update function I just call falcon_visual_vectors.update(). They each start at the same origin point, but their end points (x2, y2) differ depending on what kind of vector they are (e. g. horizontal velocity vector, vertical velocity vector, both).
My problem is: when I pass a list into the function (that is the list f9.v_vector_m_s (v stands for velocity, initially [0;0]) ... so the first vector consisting of both the horizontal and the vertical component)
it displays the vector properly, since (I believe) instead of passing the initial coordinates 0;0, python passes the entire list and later in the function, when the function looks into the list, it finds out, that the coordinates are no longer 0;0, but for example 100;100 so the vector displays properly
But as soon as I want to visualize just the horizontal component of that vector i.e. I input just the horizontal x value of that vector and leave the vertical value as 0, (I believe) that python passes just the initial coordinates 0;0, meaning, that the update function always adds 0;0 to x2,y2, instead of the current, updated coordinates, so the vector doesn't display at all, since the line's end point matches it's staring point
so how can I tell the update function, to look into the first index of f9.v_m_s list every time it updates the vector's coordinates?
class VisualVector:
    def __init__(self, coordinates, color, visual_enlargement_factor) -> None:
        self.pyglet_component = pyglet.shapes.Line(0,0,0,0,3,color,sw_batch)
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.visual_enlargement_factor = visual_enlargement_factor

class FalconVisualVectors:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.vectors = []

    def new_vector(self, coordinates, color, visual_enlargement_factor):
        vector = VisualVector(coordinates, color, visual_enlargement_factor)
        self.vectors.append(vector)

    def update(self):
        for vector in self.vectors:
            vector.pyglet_component.position = falcon_screen_location_point_px.position
            vector.pyglet_component.x2 = falcon_screen_location_point_px.x + m_into_px(vector.coordinates[0]) * vector.visual_enlargement_factor
            vector.pyglet_component.y2 = falcon_screen_location_point_px.y + m_into_px(vector.coordinates[1]) * vector.visual_enlargement_factor

falcon_visual_vectors = FalconVisualVectors()
#f9.v_vector_m_s = [0,0] <-- later gets updated
#v in v_vector_m_s stands for velocity
falcon_visual_vectors.new_vector(f9.v_vector_m_s, RED, 500) #velocity vector
falcon_visual_vectors.new_vector((f9.v_vector_m_s[0], 0), BLUE, 500) #horizontal velocity vector

btw, m_into_px just transforms meters into pixels
...
I've managed to solve it by adding two booleans to each vector, which determine, which component (horizontal, vertical or both) should be added to the vector's origin point.
But the question remains: how can I pass the variable itself into the function instead of the number the variable is pointing at?
class VisualVector:
    def __init__(self, coordinates, access_0, access_1, color, visual_enlargement_factor) -> None:
        self.pyglet_component = pyglet.shapes.Line(0,0,0,0,3,color,sw_batch)
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.access_0 = access_0
        self.access_1 = access_1
        self.visual_enlargement_factor = visual_enlargement_factor

class FalconVisualVectors:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.vectors = []

    def new_vector(self, coordinates, access_0, access_1, color, visual_enlargement_factor):
        vector = VisualVector(coordinates, access_0, access_1, color, visual_enlargement_factor)
        self.vectors.append(vector)

    def update(self):
        for vector in self.vectors:
            vector.pyglet_component.position = falcon_screen_location_point_px.position
            vector.pyglet_component.x2 = falcon_screen_location_point_px.x
            vector.pyglet_component.y2 = falcon_screen_location_point_px.y
            if vector.access_0: 
                vector.pyglet_component.x2 += m_into_px(vector.coordinates[0]) * vector.visual_enlargement_factor
            if vector.access_1: 
                vector.pyglet_component.y2 += m_into_px(vector.coordinates[1]) * vector.visual_enlargement_factor


falcon_visual_vectors = FalconVisualVectors()
#f9.v_vector_m_s = [0, 0] <-- later gets updated
#v in v_vector_m_s stands for velocity
falcon_visual_vectors.new_vector(f9.v_vector_m_s, True, True, RED, 500) #velocity vector
falcon_visual_vectors.new_vector(f9.v_vector_m_s, True, False, BLUE, 500) #horizontal velocity vector


I think your vectors shouldn't be dicts, but instances of another class...

Yup, I changed it

I got the idea of passing a function, which once called in the update function, would return a list/tuple, in which one element would consist of either the horizontal or vertical component of the vectors coordinates, i.e. point at the desired changeable value.
While passing the function, I would need to specify the list/tuple, that I want to return, so I would need to specify the function's parameter, resulting in the function getting called and thus returning the initial coordinates [0;0] and thus still passing the initial values into the update function.
However, I found out, that lambda function doesn't require a parameter and that it returns the expression it is provided with.
In other words, I can pass the lambda function with an expression and that expression being the list/tuple, which it returns.
so here is the more convenient solution:
class VisualVector:
    def __init__(self, coordinates, color, visual_enlargement_factor) -> None:
        self.pyglet_component = pyglet.shapes.Line(0,0,0,0,3,color,sw_batch)
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.visual_enlargement_factor = visual_enlargement_factor

class FalconVisualVectors:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.vectors = []

    def new_vector(self, coordinates, color, visual_enlargement_factor):
        vector = VisualVector(coordinates, color, visual_enlargement_factor)
        self.vectors.append(vector)

    def update(self):
        for vector in self.vectors:
            vector.pyglet_component.position = falcon_screen_location_point_px.position
            coordinates = vector.coordinates()
            vector.pyglet_component.x2 = falcon_screen_location_point_px.x + m_into_px(coordinates[0]) * vector.visual_enlargement_factor
            vector.pyglet_component.y2 = falcon_screen_location_point_px.y + m_into_px(coordinates[1]) * vector.visual_enlargement_factor

falcon_visual_vectors = FalconVisualVectors()
#f9.v_vector_m_s = [0,0] <-- later gets updated
#v in v_vector_m_s stands for velocity
falcon_visual_vectors.new_vector(lambda: game.g_visual_vector_m_s2, BLUE, 500) #gravitational vector
falcon_visual_vectors.new_vector(lambda: f9.v_vector_m_s, RED, 500) #velocity vector
falcon_visual_vectors.new_vector(lambda: (f9.v_vector_m_s[0], 0), BLACK, 500) #horizontal velocity vector
falcon_visual_vectors.new_vector(lambda: (0, f9.v_vector_m_s[1]), BLACK, 500) #vertical velocity vector

Btw, another advantage of lambda is that if I am taking/returning a changeable value, I can modify it in lambda's expression: e.g. abs(), round(), multiplication, division etc.
e.g.:
labels.new_label("Gravitational acceleration [m/s2]: #", lambda: abs(round(game.g / 1000, 2)), sw_batch)

Every time game.g gets updated, we can see a modified number of game.g on the label based on the modification inside lambda's expression.
If you have any questions or would like to lecture me on my imprecise verbalism, feel free to tell me.
